# Forward root mail to external address via postfix

Tags: email, postfix

I'm trying to redirect root mail on a CentOS 8 host to an external mail external@externaldomain.tld, so I get an email notifications when cronjobs fail.

The receiving mail server is on Uberspace.de.
I set up a domain I own in postfix on the sending CentOS 8 host;

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
mydomain = mydomain.org
myorigin = $mydomain
```

as otherwise (like when the FROM domain has no MX record) all mail sent to the recipient mail server on uberspace would be rejected with

```
said: 550 No MX for your FROM address (in reply to MAIL FROM command)
```

Testing the mail with `echo test | mail -s "test" external@externaldomain.tld` works.

I tried forwarding via/root/.forward

```
externaluser@externalmail.com
```

`echo test | mail -s "test" root`, but now mails are sent to root@mydomain.org

I tried forwarding via /etc/aliases

```
root: externaluser@externalmail.com
```

`sudo newaliases && echo test | mail -s "test" root`, but now mails are sent to root@mydomain.org

Has anyone some ideas how I could achieve getting all mail to root forwarded to externaluser@externalmail.com ?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I was struggling with this too, followed multitude of tutorials and ended up with working solution, but hard to say which part of which tutorial exactly was it.

Anyways, to get `echo test | mail -s test root` automatically sent to myaddress@gmail.com address same as `echo test | mail -s test myaddress@gmail.com` does on my Raspberry Pi Zero:

I edited `/etc/postfix/main.cf` like so:

```
myhostname = zero.lan

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Raspbian)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = yes

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains =
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_use_tls = yes
compatibility_level = 2
```

then edited `/etc/aliases` like so:

```
postmaster: root
root: localuser
localuser: myaddress@gmail.com
```

and ran `sudo newaliases` and `sudo systemctl reload postfix` and that did the trick for me.